# Why is it better to mock repository class than Eloquent models?

Tags: php, laravel

I know what dependency injection is and why to use it (it's better to inject class than to use new keyword because it's kind of makes impossible to test it later). I'm going to talk about Laravel's ways of how to write controllers.

Way 1)
Let's say I have the following function in controller and I want to test it.

```
public function index() {
        $allActors = \App\Actor::all();
        foreach($allActors as $actor){
            $actor->name="gio";
        }
        return $allActors;
}
```

As you see, controller and model is tightly coupled. My question is why I can't test this method? I looked through Laravel's mockery and I think it could be tested. What I'd do is before making a call to index method, I'd mock the `\App\Actor` and what it should return. Why shouldn't I follow this idea?

Way 2)

```
protected $actor;
public function __construct(\App\Actor $actor){
    $this->actor = $actor;
}
 
public function index() {
    $allActors = $this->actor->all();
    foreach($allActors as $actor){
        $actor->name="gio";
    }
    return $allActors;
}
```

Now you think this could be tested? how? One thing I can think of is before creating new controller, I'd create new class that extends Actor model and override its functions, in this case `all()` function and get the results from file.

The main question is why can't I test it in the first example and in the second example? Which one is better for DI? It seems like the second option is DI, but I looked through Laravel's docs and I think the first example can be mocked still. But I also read that Eloquent models can't be mocked. I am seeking a whole idea about all of this.

Comment: I would move the `\App\Actor::all()` call to a separate method in the controller class, mock the controller and that method and then test the mock instead of an instance of the controller itself. Your second option involves creating dummy instances and changing static method to non-static so I would definitely not go that way.